# Need a calendar for Joomla 2.5 administrator to select room availability dates

Tags: calendar, joomla2.5

I am working on a Joomla site (Joomla 2.5), and there I need a calendar to be shown on a page on administration panel in order to select the availability dates for rooms.  I know that Joomla has a built-in calendar control for selecting dates on forms, but my requirement is to show a full calendar with next/previous month navigation and also with checkboxes for each date.

Can anybody suggest a way to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented something similar with fullcalendar.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

It will take a bit of work to get it up and running, as it will pull in your dates from an ajax request, so you need to write a controller function fullcalendar can call.